# Why do new phones and tablets with a USB Type-C connector use a USB Type-A charger?

Tags: usb-c, power-delivery

I have noticed that many relatively new phones and tablets with USB Type-C connectors (e.g., Nokia 6.1 or Samsung Galaxy Tab A T-590) are bundled with USB Type-A fast chargers (e.g., 12V, 1.5A) and a USB Type-C-to-Type-A cable.

**What are the advantages of this practice?**

It would seem much more natural to me to ship USB Type-C devices with USB Type-C chargers. Charging could probably be faster (or at least more standards-compliant) through a pure USB Type-C cable that supports USB Power Delivery specification revision 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a cheap and effective solution.

Which uses up stocks of chargers that work, while not at top speed but more than sufficient. Most users, or at least a lot, charge overnight so the charging time is not too much of an issue.

Comment: Another point is that many dont have PC with USB type C connector so manufacturers would need to include additional adapter for user convenience.

Comment: @Rokta most things I purchase only come with one power supply and one cable, if you want others then you purchase the ones you need.

Comment: But wouldn't the practice of shipping Type-A chargers have depleted the excessive stock by now? Type-C devices (and chargers) have been available for years. I am fairly sure that these chargers are newly manufactured. Chargers from 5 years ago could not even deliver 12V 1.5A. These chargers _do_ charge fast, they just don't do it the "intended" way.

Comment: @Zoltan Did you miss "cheap and effective"?

Comment: Yes, I focused on the longer second paragraph. From the first one, "effective" would apply to Type-C charging as well, so that leaves "cheap". So if I understand correctly, your point is that a Type-C charger would be significantly more expensive, or even if just _slightly_ more expensive, the extra cost would still not be justified because a less elegant but cheaper solution can fulfill the same purpose. I was hoping in a more technical reason, but then it seems it's purely for cost efficiency.

Comment: @Zoltan then you obviously have not met some of the bean counters who tread all over engineering plans and decisions in search of the "God Profit"...